# Is Spring hard compared to Ruby on Rails?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, spring

If I have little to no experience in either of them, but know enough Java and Ruby to be comfortable, is one framework harder to learn than the other?  Is one easier to use for the beginner on these?

I know it is hard to answer.  Just looking for general thoughts on it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both Spring and Ruby on Rails share the "convention over configuration" moto. This reduces code lines significantly. Ruby on Rails is a Web Framework and it could be compared with Spring MVC, together with an ORM tool like Hibernate.

One could say that Spring together with Spring MVC or another MVC framework and Hibernate are the closest that you can get to Ruby on Rails for the Java world.

However, Spring has a much wider scope than RoR.

Comment: Which aspects of Spring do you consider to utilise Convention over Configuration? For the version of Spring that I'm somewhat familiar with, you have to write reams of XML configuration. Later versions let you use annotations instead, but it's still configuration of at least some things that could probably be inferred.

Comment: In Spring 2.x+ spring introduced CoC in MVC, see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-coc.  Also using annotations dramatically reduces the XML configuration necessary for all other Spring aspects.

Comment: configuration via annotations is still configuration

Comment: I agree with John Topley...heard that annotations were good, but the majority of stuff I've seen out there still uses XML config and shitloads of it

Comment: I'm using Spring & I can't say it convention over configuration... at least compared to Grails (a branch child of Spring which is inspired by RoR)

Comment: sorry this is a really old topic obviously but i get SOOO annoyed when i hear the argument that java is horrible because of lots of XML configuration. You can pretty much use the default configs generated by an IDE or generator tool (Roo?) & then change very little in your actual code (complaining about annotations is almost akin to complaining about having to write that your model inherits from "ActiveRecord"). RoR people just seem to like that it hides all the default config from them whereas I think in the Java world its more accepted because folks acknowledge that someone else may need it

Comment: Could you elaborate on how "Spring has a much wider scope than RoR"? I would appreciate your insights on this as I am currently learning both Spring and RoR.

Comment: @RestInPeace: RoR is mainly about web applications. Spring has evolved to include a wide range of projects, mainly targeted to enterprise applications. Have a look at: https://spring.io/projects

Comment: to revisit my previous comment -- after a year+ with Spring, i still have not touched any XML config :)... there are some config classes in my projects, but mainly to register resolvers and my own custom beans. So in a sense this isn't configuration so much as app code. Most of my classes have a few annotations, but they are extremely welcome/powerful/helpful. And yes, the patterns it has taught me extend well beyond web... it has prepared me for app development in a way RoR never even came close to. YMMV but my code is now more efficient, simple, well-patterned. Brain work better now :P

Comment: @RestInPeace, to address your question specifically: Spring is actually light-weight & flexible enough that it can be used for almost any type of Java application without being a performance hindrance. It is a middleware transparent enough for any type of app. For example, it would be easy to create a high-performance data-mining algorithm that swaps in different modules based on which profile is "active" (specified at runtime). I think of it sortof as a meta-framework... it just enhances productivity with freeform code so that any design pattern set becomes more modular/manageable

Comment: *Spring Boot* is all about *Convention over Configuration*.

Answer (score 41):

I don't like this comparison.

You should compare Grails or Spring Roo to Rails. Groovy Grails is a RoR like system built on Spring that uses Groovy for rails-like DSLs. Roo is a vaguely railish pure java DSL for RoR like apps.

I really hate to say it this way but Spring is a platform. You use it to wire Java technologies together. You can use it for non-web, non-database, zero UI apps. You can use it to write batch servers. You can use it to write clients.

Rails isn't the same. I really like rails for data driven web apps but I shudder at the thought of writing a batch processing system in rails.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Spring != Rails. Spring is more like Express.js or Flask.py.  They have different goals and can't be directly compared.

Comment: @Banjocat - in what way is Spring more like Flask? In java world we have microframeworks like Spark (not to be confused with Apache Spark), which would be equivalent to Flask. Spring has no equivalent in Python world except Spring Python. Spring is much more than web - it started as a DI framework and now is a comprehensive configuration framework.

Answer (score 23):

After working with Rails, Spring (and just about any other Java coding) feels tedious and time consuming.

Comment: ditto for .net and its various frameworks

Comment: Until you get a very complex business application that requires hundreds of classes and you can't figure out class to pass in to what constructor

Comment: @JohnBaker, very true.  I agree with you from my personal experience.  Spring might require a bit more work, but for me, it is the superior choice when it comes to large and complex applications.

Comment: Rails supporters (i am an ex-RoR guy myself who switched to Java/Spring) seem to push the mantra that simplicity is best, but Spring is complex for a reason: to support large projects & complex/distributed design patterns. If you want to code a simple MVC app in Java that is fine too, it will work its just not optimized -- Spring & the EE technologies are for people that are trying to manage object lifecycle in a large, complex, efficient enterprise implementation. They're not trying to avoid these issues, they CHOOSE to embrace them for performance gain. Different strokes...

Answer (score 11):

I have recently moved to using Spring MVC + WebFlow from 4 years on ruby on rails.

Ruby is great rails is the productivity egde. However, spring MVC is geared more towards the enterprise with layers of design and patterns over patterns.

I don't say it is rubbish it's interesting to learn a different approach towards UI development.

You can not compare the two. Spring MVC is more tailored towards designs that can be reused in Portlet development or development of webflows that can be altered without changing a lot of java code.

There are subframeworks like spring security and not to mention Aspects in all shapes and kinds I find all this a big learning curve. The views can be rendered with JSF or JSP/JSTL.

Honestly, I think java is a language that has not evolved in ages and people have had substantial investments in this stack they have hacked and overwritten ways around code.
Annotations and XML or be it Generics they are all with an aim to make the language cater to ever increasing and evolving world around it.

Contrasting that to a modern dynamic language like ruby there is a lot of productivity difference. Ruby is dead simple programmer friendly and superior in every way.

Rails is a very opinionated piece of software dictated by what DHH and the rest think and want in it.

Yes, its great for web app development in fact you will feel you have acquired the missing thing when you start programming rails.

The trouble is rails has received a lot of negative publicity over the years. I am not sure about it's future at this time and choosing between something proven vs something that is getting cloned in every new web framework is a risk.

ASP.net mvc, grails cakePHP every popular MVC framework out there has cloned rails.

Is spring hard compared to rails?

I think if you apply your mind both are equal in terms of the learning curve.

Comment: I agree with you in general, but can you define "enterprise"?  What exactly is an enterprise and why is Spring (specifically) better suited for it?

Answer (score 10):

Comparing RoR to Spring directly is not a direct or easy comparison.

RoR focuses rather tightly on developing websites easily.  RoR does a great job of making crafting pages, linking them together, and persisting data very easy.  RoR was designed explicitly with web development in mind, and is a great tool for this.  That said, when you need to do more "enterprise" development (messaging, integration, etc.), or have a need to do something that does not fit into the RoR conventions, you will feel some pain.

That said, Spring has many facets: Spring IoC, Spring AOP, SpringMVC, etc. that is aimed at solving a myriad of different development issues faced by developers.  Spring has a very wide assortment of technologies that will ease most development challenges you will face.

To directly answer your question, it directly depends on your requirements.  If you are developing simply database backed web applications, RoR will allow you to quickly and easily develop an application and is easier for the beginner to get started with.  Spring on the other hand has a steeper learning curve and more configuration necessary, but gives you much more flexibility and power.

Once facet that I think is often missing from this type of discussion is the power of the community, tooling, and libraries available.  Java/Spring is a mature platform with extensive community and tooling support, while Ruby/RoR has a great community, the tooling is still catching up IMO.

Comment: I don't see any evidence that Java/Spring gives you more "flexibility and power" than Rails. You also emphasize that Rails is better for the beginner, implying it's worse in some way for veterans.  Just because something is hard or easy to use in the beginning does it not mean it's powerful or worse for veterans, respectively.

Comment: i didnt really get the "for beginners" dig from his answer. i, however, develop in both Java and RoR & totally understand the "flexibility & power" comment... RoR has a much more limited scope in terms of performance & prescribed design patterns. This is just a fact, pretty much.... Rails is a specific type of front-end app framework whereas Spring is not.

Answer (score 5):

The thing about Spring is that it is mainly two things:

1. It is essentially an "adapter" or "facade" for existing technologies and libraries; and
2. It is *philosophically* different from say J2EE in that it is all about dependency injection or inversion of control, which is a fundamentally different approach than what came previously.

For (1) for example, Spring can do things like help ease the pain of what JMS provider you use or do things like translate exceptions generated by different databases into Spring runtime DataAccessExceptions.

Spring is typically labelled a lightweight container for this reason. In the Spring world ("application context"), vendor differences typically become just an issue of configuration. Dependency injection does a lot of things like making testing much easier (done right).

The biggest challenge in learning and using Spring is learning to think that way if you haven't previously done anything like it.

Other than that, there's really not a lot to Spring and that's a good thing. Spring doesn't get in your way. You choose whatever technologies you want to use and Spring nearly always just makes using them and integrating them easier.

Once you get into the DI/IoC way of thinking.

Answer (score 3):

Spring is quite big, it has two facets *that I know of* the dependency injection and AOP. Ruby on rails is very much geared up towards writing web apps.

If you are looking to write a web app I would expect you would find ROR easier to use as it is much closer to the problem domain.

If you wanted to use spring to write a web app you would most likely need to learn a few more technologies as well which may get a bit overwhelming. However if you are just learning for fun, combining spring with the head first patterns book can be fun.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this question is really about Spring MVC. One of the hallmarks of Ruby on Rails is "convention over configuration". If you use the right names, you spare yourself a lot of work writing configuration files. With Spring, you're probably going to need to go ahead and type in a lot of that configuration.

Also Rails routing is much more powerful and concise than the alternatives in Spring. In recent releases, Spring has tried to move to more of a convention over configuration model, but it will still seem burdensome to a Rails developer.

Comment: I think routing is very annoying in Rails.  Spring makes life easier.

Answer (score 2):

I've worked with both somewhat extensively, and I found Spring and the most popular "add-ons" hibernate, JSF, JSP, Rich Faces, etc extremely hard to use.

Mostly it was because of a personal dissatisfaction with the documentation and the available books and tutorials on the full stack.  Also it just is nowhere near as user friendly of a framework as Rails.  It really feels like just showed a better way to develop web apps in almost every way.

Comment: Spring is an incredibly well documented framework. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: Just because there is lots of documentation doesn't mean it's good documentation.  In my experience it didn't answer a lot of the questions I had.

Comment: The amount is not the issue here.  I believe that Spring is intended for a higher technical level, Enterprise.  Rails does not require a solid background to start building web applications with.

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb with a few exceptions they actually do basically the same thing - spring just makes it harder to do simple things

Comment: Things may have changed. Spring to me is much simpler and have better documentations

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb I don't think its a simple as spring == enterprise or if it is even at a higher level.  the main difference is it is java on the jvm (you can achieve the roughly the same results with jruby on rails).   at the time of writing the difficulty in getting up to speed on spring vs rails was just insane.  i think with spring boot it is probably a lot easier now though

Comment: also the play java framework i think is a more practical example of good documentation for me at least   - agreed i think spring is probably harder to grasp at times because it's not necessarily only used for web based projects like rails is